# Strapi Menu Plugin on click of a relation throws 405

Tags: menu, strapi, http-status-code-405, menu-items

`I am trying to add a Relation in the Menu, but the relation items arent loading.

This request keeps hitting :

POST /admin/plugins/menus/edit/menus/relations/page_otm?limit=20&start=0 (0 ms) 405
instead of :
POST /menus/relations/page_otm?limit=20&start=0 (0 ms) 405
strapi-server.js:

'use strict';

`module.exports = plugin => { // Get current` MenuItem` attributes.
const defaultAttrs = plugin.contentTypes[ 'menu-item' ].schema.attributes;

// Define custom attributes for `MenuItem` the same way they would be defined
// on any other schema.
const customAttrs = {
page_otm: {
type: 'relation',
relation: 'oneToOne',
target: 'api::page.page',
},
};

// Extend the `MenuItem` content type with custom attributes.
plugin.contentTypes[ 'menu-item' ].schema.attributes = {
...defaultAttrs,
...customAttrs,
};

return plugin;
};`

plugins.js:

`menus: { config: { maxDepth: 2, layouts: { menuItem: {  link: [ { input: { label: 'Linked Page', name: 'page_otm', type: 'relation', }, grid: { col: 6, }, }, ], }, }, }, },`

strapi version: 4.2.3
strapi-plugin-menus version: 1.0.2

I tried setting the STRAPI_ADMIN_BACKEND_URL variable in env which actually helps redirecting to right call, but our pipeline is such that we build code once and use the same in diff environments -> dev,qa,prod. and this variable has to be set before build and does not automatically takes the updated value on env file.`